# How to make a file 'download' when clicked in Windows IE

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, css, internet-explorer, download

I have a button in a form tag that generates a CSV file and prompts a download when a user clicks it.

When I try to accomplish this in IE, IE tries to open the file with IE which it shouldn't. I just want it to download the file.

My HTML :

```
<FORM accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post" action="/generate_csv?calc[]total_interest=189.08">
  <DIV style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; display: inline;"><INPUT name="utf8" value="✓" type="hidden">
    <INPUT name="authenticity_token" value="4o1dEDoFbbDoc3scpnhDaQpPtpFM5NitTOrYQA0AU5k=" type="hidden">
  </DIV>
  <INPUT id="print_csv" name="commit" value="Print CSV" type="submit">
</FORM>
```

My Rails Controller :

```
headers['Content-Disposition'] = "attachment;"
send_data(csv_string,
  :type => 'text/csv; charset=utf-8; header=present; disposition=attachment',
  :filename => @filename,
  :disposition => 'attachment')
```

Any ideas how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try the following.  In your controller, when you generate the CSV file you are probably sending it using send_data or send_file. Is that correct? If so, you probably need to set the disposition as 'attachment' instead of simply sending the file or the data. For example:

```
send_data @csv, :type => 'text/csv', :disposition => 'attachment', :filename => 'generate_csv.csv'
```

or

```
send_file '/path/to.csv', :type => 'text/csv', :disposition => 'attachment'
```

Another thing you can do is modify your routes to include a format. For example:

```
match 'generate_csv.csv' => 'csv#generate_csv'
```

You can convert your post request to a get request like this:

```
<%= link_to "Print CSV", '/generate_csv?calc[]total_interest=189.08' %>
```

Comment: Ah great point, I am using those `send_data` with faster_csv, and like you mentioned I added the disposition attachment variable, but it doesn't seem to help.

Comment: Could it be because it's coming from a submit button?

Comment: It could be. Have you tried making it a simple link_to or a GET request?

Comment: Another thing I would do is open up Firebug or Chrome Developer Tools in your browser and make sure you can see a "Content-Disposition: attachment" header coming back from your application. If you can't it might mean that the header is getting removed somewhere (maybe in Nginx or Apache).

Comment: @Pan good point. No I don't see content-disposition in the headers. Just the UTF-8.

Comment: Sorry to keep bothering, you've been a great help. But I was curious if you knew how to replace the submit tag *with* a simple link_to and a GET request.

Comment: I would make sure you restart your server or varnish - incase the file is cached with headers somewhere. Also, I would try adding a :filename => 'generate_csv.csv' to the send_data command to make sure you are passing a filename back as well.

Comment: I also updated my answer with the filename suggestion and a different routing suggestion.

Comment: Got the link_to working.. haha except for IE :) . updating the overkill above.

Comment: You have a lot of extra stuff going on in your controller. Pick one way to set the content disposition and make sure it's getting passed to your browser. And only set the type to 'text/csv'. If you want to set other headers use headers[]. Also, I would recommend trying my alternative route with the .csv to force the format.

Comment: All great ideas. Thanks. I think i finally met my programmatic match. Tried everything. Even converting all this to a json object and passing it and it still failed. Tried your alternative matches..kept rebooting the server..no errors, logs say its going through, but no prompt. nothing gets downloaded.

Comment: @Pan! I Finally got it! You were right all along about the hidden fields. Had to rewire a huge chunk of my application to get it right, and now it works perfectly. it all makes sense! Ha..wow..10 hours..

Answer (score 1):

The program generating the CSV needs to add an HTTP header for `Content-Disposition`:

```
 Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=<file name.ext>
```

See http://www.jtricks.com/bits/content_disposition.html.

Answer (score 0):

To hint a browser that it should download a file, make sure you send the `Content-Disposition: attachment` header from your application.